# Ionic ReactJS Binding element 'appProps' implicitly has an 'any' type. TS7031

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Im also getting an error ***Binding element 'C' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031***

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AppliedRoute({ component: C, appProps, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => <C {...props} {...appProps} />} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're about to destructure React Props here, you want to type check the whole object being passed instead of checking every destructured property by itself.

Your code should then look something like this:

```
interface AppliedRouteProps {
    component: C;
    appProps: IAppProps;
    rest: any;
}

export default function AppliedRoute({ component, appProps, ...rest }: AppliedRouteProps) {
...
```